# C++ regex_search for unicode returns \341 \272

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm using native C++ regex to search unicode in a input string.

My input string is unicode like "\u1000"

It only happens with the unicode range over \u1050.

If I search for \u1040, it's fine.

```
#include <regex>

...
smatch matches;
regex zawgyi_regex("[\u1050-\u109f]"); // something wrong here

while(regex_search(input, matches, zawgyi_regex)) {
    for (string x:matches)
        cout << "match: ->" << x << "<- " << endl;

    cout << "---" << endl;
    input = matches.suffix().str();
}
```

I get the following results.

```
match: ->\341<-
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: "what i'm doing wrong" perhaps using std::regex with UTF-8 encoded strings. What is your platform and compiler version?

Comment: @n.m. i'm on OSX and Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)

Comment: Try converting to wchar_t and using std::wregex. UTF-8 and c++ regexes don't mix well.

Comment: String literals and non-ASCII characters don't mix either, I'm not sure what will actually end up in a string if you write `"\u1050"`. If you want UTF-8 in that string, you should either do so explicitly: `"\xe1\x81\x90"`, or if supported use Unicode literals: `u8"\u1050"`.

Comment: thank @roeland it's pretty weird in C++. mmm